# How to do something with the parameter used in creating a new instance in AutoFac?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

I am looking to do something like this:
(Free handed)

```
 container.RegisterType<MyParam>().InstancePerDependency();
 container.RegisterType<MyType>().WithParameter<MyParam>((ctx, myParam, newInstance) => { 
     ctx.Resolve<SomeOtherType>().Bind(myParam, newInstance);
 });
```

Is it possible to do with Autofac?

Comment: You might want try to explain [what the problem is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) you are trying to solve.

Comment: [Have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/parameters.html#parameters-with-lambda-expression-components)

Comment: @Steven I want to make sure a type gets a new instance of a type and keep track of which instance is assigned which instance.

Comment: @TravisIllig Yes, I saw that page, but it doesn't seem to be able to do what I want it to. Or at least I can't see how I would be able to acess the resolved/registered type and the parameter at the same time.

Comment: What you're showing in the pseudocode and what's in the docs (how to access the parameter) is the same. If that's not answering the question, the question isn't clear enough. Perhaps there is context you're assuming we have that we actually don't? (Update THE QUESTION, don't just iterate over it in comments...)